# Back to Previous Route in Handling the Hardware Back Button in Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using this code ([here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html#handling-the-hardware-back-button-in-android)) for Handling the Hardware Back Button in Android.

I have nested Route and in this code when you click on Back Button, go to `initialRoute`.

My Route is such as:  `Home => PoolList => PoolDetails => Cart`

In `Cart` Route by clicking on Back Button, back to `Home`. I want to back such as:

`Home <= PoolList <= PoolDetails <= Cart`

How to change this code?

```
import React from "react";
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";
import { addNavigationHelpers, NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const AppNavigation = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    PoolList: { screen: PoolListScreen },
    PoolDetails: { screen: PoolDetailsScreen },
    Cart: { screen: CartScreen },
  },
  {
     contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
     drawerPosition: 'right'
 }
);

class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }
  onBackPress = () => {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    if (nav.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    const navigation = addNavigationHelpers({
      dispatch,
      state: nav,
      addListener,
    });

    return <AppNavigation navigation={navigation} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. So you want to go straight from `Cart` to `Home` by pressing back button?

Comment: Try NavigationActions.goBack(null);

Comment: @ThoVu I want to go straight from `Cart` to `PoolDetails` by pressing back button.